# SLF4j not writing to a log file

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, logback

In my web project I am trying to use SLF4j with logback , I have pasted the SLF4j xml settings and also the section of POM  ,when I start the application on Tomacat in local machine. I do not see any errors nor the logs are generated.

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./myapp.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>./myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./myapp_debug.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>./myapp_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <!-- logger name="com.base22" level="TRACE"/ -->
  <logger name="com.sample.app" level="TRACE" />
  <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="java.sql" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="ERROR" />

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Section of Maven Pom for Logging jars

```
<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Inside a webcontainer use Java util logging as the backend so the container will collect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I fixed the problem made couple of changes ,

POM.XML

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

In logback.xml

changed ./myapp.log to ${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log

and I can see the logs generated now in Tomcat/Logs directory

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting way to deal with this.

First, verify that you have no conflicting bindings (i.e. log4j getting pulled in). Since you are using maven, run the following command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=:log4j,:commons-logging
```

If you see any of those dependencies included transitively, add exclusions to the dependencies that are bringing those in.

Secondly, add `jul-to-slf4j` to your dependency list (corresponding to the version you are using). You should put any and all bindings outside of slf4j-api as `runtime` scope.

Thirdly, add the file src/main/resources/logging.properties with the contents

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

If you are launching tomcat through the standard startup or catalina scripts it will automatically configure a "log manager" that will allow you to override a context specific java.util.logging (jul) configuration.

See [here](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) for more information.

Comment: +1 for ensuring commons-logging isn't on your classpath.  In my experience slf4j and commons-logging don't play well together, and one of the symptoms is exactly what OP describes - no errors, no data in log files.

Comment: if you turn on the log4j debug flag to true in your JVM argument, you should see multiple bindings from your local maven repository jars happening when slf4j initializes and shows as warning. Just exclude those.  And Commons-loggings are one of them as well as ch.qos.logback.

Answer (score -4):

may be the log file location that you searching might be wrong, please search for the log file with it name.